# How do I change the app owner on Parse.com?

Tags: parse-platform

I'm an intern and am the owner of two apps on Parse.com. When I leave this company, I want to be able to change the app owner from me to a coworker so he can add collaborators, but there doesn't seem to be a way to do this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

From their [FAQ](https://www.parse.com/plans/faq)

> How do I delete my account? **How do I transfer an app?**
>
> Get in touch with us via the button at the bottom of this page. (referring to the "Contact Us" button)